# How do I find the x and y values in an array where the array is divided equally in a cartesian orientation?

Tags: python, numpy, output, coordinates, cartesian

What I'm trying to do is simply find and define an x and y coordinate for the highest number in the array.

For example, 50000 would output: x = 2, y = 2. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

I created this code below:

```
data_array = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 50000],
              [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
              [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
              [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
              [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]

highest_num = data_array[0][0]
x = 0
y = 0

# looping from 0 to len(data_array)-1
for i in range(len(data_array)):

    # looping from 0 to len(data_array[i])-1
    for j in range(len(data_array[i])):

        # checking data_array[x][y] is less than data_array[i][j]
        if data_array[x][y] < data_array[i][j]:

            # updating x and y
            x = i
            y = j
            highest_num = data_array[i][j] 

# printing the values of highest_num, x and y
print("highest_num =", highest_num)
print("x =", x)
print("y =", y)
```

But I would get x = 0, y = 4. I wanted to reference the middle of the array which is 12 and make the output be x = 2, y = 2.

Can this be accomplished without numpy where? I want the points to track with the max wherever it is.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by '4 would output: x=2, y=2'. Please clarify!

Comment: I would suggest to use `numpy.where` with a condition `array==4`, but I don't know your logic to obtain `x = 2, y = 2`. it would be `x = 4, y = 0` instead.

Comment: Is 4 a value or an index in your linear array. Your example is confusing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant in a cartesian plane where 12 is (0,0). I totally omitted that. That was the biggest struggle because of the placement.

Comment: @ceilowens Please edit your question with that additional information instead of a comment.

Comment: This question does not make sense

Answer (score 0):

Modify 2 lines in your program:

```
print("x =", x-2)
print("y =", y+2)
```

Comment: y should be reversed as well, row start zero from top

Answer (score 0):

if you could use numpy do the argmax like this then find the coordinate (row col) and coordinate switch to chartersian (reverse y) then both subtracte the half , (considering it is even in both dimentions.

```
idx = np.argmax(data_array)
m, n =  len(data_array), len(data_array[0])

r, c = m - (idx // n) - 1  , idx % n
y , x = r - (m // 2), c - (n // 2)
```

if not just use the code your writetn to find maximum index.